# Show that $\int_0^2 (x-1)\,\,f\left((x-1)^2 \right)\,dx=0 $

Tags: real-analysis

Show that  $$\int_0^2 (x-1)\,\,f\left((x-1)^2 \right)\,dx=0 $$

I need help.

Comment: What is f?  How is it defined?

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

make the substitution $$t=x-1$$

it becomes $$A=\int_{-1}^1tf(t^2)dt$$

is the function integrand odd or even?

now, put $$u=-t$$ it gives

$$A=\int_1^{-1}uf(u^2)du=-A$$

thus $$2A=0$$

done!

Answer (score -1):

Let u=(x-1)^2 and the take the derivative to both sides. Leaving us with
du=2(x-1)dx , solving for dx, we obtain: dx=du/(2(x-1)), then we see that:

∫(x-1)f((x-1)^2)dx = ∫(x-1)f(u)dx = ∫(x-1)*f(u)*(du/(2*(x-1))) = (1/2)∫f(u)du.

Change the bounds from [0,2] in respect to x, to the bounds in respect to u, hence, u1=(2-1)^2=1 and u2=(0-1)^2=1. Therefore the bounds are [1,1], hence **no area** is covered, therefore nothing else is needed to determine that the answer.  This integral is equal to **0**.

Comment: That is plainly wrong

Comment: This doesn't work. Integration by substitution requires the substitution map to be a differentiable bijection between two intervals but $u(x) =  (x-1)^2$ is not injective for $x \in [0,2]$.

Comment: then the substitution may remain so. ∫(x-1)f((x-1)^2)dx = ∫t.f(t^2)dt = . in [-1,1] so dt\2.(t)=dx so = (1/2)∫f(t^2)dt replacement = 1\2[F(1)-F(-1)]'=1\2(0-0)=0.